# Photoshop: unable to nudge a text layer

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, selections

I am getting this error in Adobe Photoshop CC when I try to nudge my text layer with the arrow keys. I was able to nudge them before in the same work session, but now they won't budge, nudge, or move an inch. Any thoughts? I've never encountered this error before.

[image]

Comment: Because Photoshop now sucks. Adobe has destroyed a good product.

Answer (score 6):

You must be having an active selection somewhere. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> then try again. Use this if you want to keep your text editable.

Or, depending on what you are trying to achieve, right click the text layer, choose 'Rasterize Type', then try again. In this case it will be impossible to edit the text afterwards.